# How to Start WAS?

Tags: iis, was

I'm trying to fire up IIS on my machine, but I've run into a range of issues.  I think it boils down to the fact that I can't start the WAS service.

I'm finally at a point where it tells me: Cannot find the file specified.

On the Properties dialog, under Path to executable, it says: C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k iissvcs.

"svchost.exe" is indeed in the System32 directory where it should be.  I'm looking for a next step in troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Rebuild your Windows is going to be the fastest way, as such an error indicates part of Windows is corrupt. You might use tools like Process Monitor to analyze if you insist, but since there is almost no documentation on the internals of the service, you won't easily figure out the cause.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks, I just ran the Windows Troubleshooter a couple of times and it fixed some dbase issues, but not my particular problem.  Can you tell me how to do a "rebuild of windows"?